# loaded assets js in symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, assets

I'm trying to integrate a template into a symfony project to change the design of my twig pages
but I can not load Js files for Css files it's good but js files I have this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $is not defined
>   at formCheck.js:1
>   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/function.js net::ERR_ABORTED 
>   404 (Not Found)
>
> VM1394 bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript 
>   requires jQuery
>
> at VM1394 bootstrap.min.js:6
>   (anonymous) @ VM1394 bootstrap.min.js:6
>
> VM1395 formCheck.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>    at VM1395 formCheck.js:1
>
> (anonymous) @ VM1395 formCheck.js:1
>
> 127.0.0.1/:36 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/function.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> VM1397 jquery.gmap.min.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   at VM1397 jquery.gmap.min.js:10
>
> (anonymous) @ VM1397 jquery.gmap.min.js:10
>   VM1399 jquery.syotimer.js:358 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   `
>   at VM1399 jquery.syotimer.js:358
>   (anonymous) @ VM1399 jquery.syotimer.js:358
>
> VM1400 jquery.vide.js:432 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'vide' of undefined

```
   {% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}"> . 
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery.gmap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery.syotimer.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery.vide.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/function.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/formCheck.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/isotope.pkgd.min.js') }}"> . 
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/lightbox.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/plugins.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/swiper.min.js') }}"></script>

    {% endblock %}
```

for the architecture of my files everything is good I already check I point to the good files thank you for your help

Comment: what's the purpose of that dot "." character at lines 2 and 9?

Comment: paths should be relative to public dir (look at the url for the 404)

Comment: Thank you I fixed the problem you have to load jquery before the other files and put the right way;